# Update price after checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a fairly simple problem (I think) that involves updating a number using jQuery. I have a DIV that holds a price for an item. Users can select a checkbox to add on to the total price. What I need is when someone clicks on a checkbox, it will add the correct amount to the DIV. When a user un-checks a checkbox, the value is subtracted. Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check-0" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="check-0">$100</label>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="price">$347</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A problem you'll encounter at first is that you have duplicate `id` attributes, which is not allowed, and will not produce desired results.

Comment: This was a mistake, the first id="check-0" should not be there. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ahh no problem, just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Do you know of any jQuery code capable of achieving this? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on something. Not sure if someone else will beat me to it though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var changePrice = function changePrice(amt, state){
    var curPrice = $('.price').text();
    curPrice = curPrice.substring(1, curPrice.length);
    if(state==true){
        curPrice = parseInt(curPrice) + parseInt(amt);
    }else{
        curPrice = parseInt(curPrice) - parseInt(amt);
    }
    curPrice = '$' + curPrice;
    $('.price').text(curPrice);
}
$(function(){
    $('#check-0').on('change', function(){
        var itemPrice = $('label[for="check-0"]').text();
        itemPrice = itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length);
    changePrice(itemPrice, $('#check-0').is(':checked'));
    });
})​;​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/r2Snu/

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is something that you could use or help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/VWRAd/

```
$(".cell").on("click", "input:checkbox", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $total = $("#price");
    var $target = $("label[for='" + $this.attr("id") + "']");

    var item_value = +($target.html().replace("$", "") || 0);
    var cur_total = +($total.html().replace("$", "") || 0);

    if ($this.prop("checked") === true) {
        cur_total += item_value;
    } else {
        cur_total -= item_value;
    }

    $total.html("$" + cur_total);
});
```

Although notice that I changed the element with the `class` of "price" to have an **`id`** of "price". It just makes sense, unless you expect to have several "price" elements.

And here is another possible way of doing it...not sure which is better:

http://jsfiddle.net/VWRAd/1/

```
$(".cell").on("click", "input:checkbox", function () {
    var $items = $(".cell").find("input:checkbox:checked");
    var $total = $("#price");
    var cur_total = 0;

    $items.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $target = $("label[for='" + $this.attr("id") + "']");
        var item_value = +($target.html().replace("$", "") || 0);

        cur_total += item_value;
    });

    $total.html("$" + cur_total);
});
```

Some things to consider - it makes sense to separate the "$" from the actual value of the item when displaying it...I'm sure you aren't storing the value with "$", so you might want a structure similar to `<label for="whatever">$<span class="the-value">100</span></label>`. It would change your jQuery selector logic a little bit, but it would prevent the need for using `.replace` so often. Also, as someone else already pointed out, it would definitely be easier to store the item's price in the checkbox's `value` attribute and retrieve it that way (instead of finding the corresponding `<label>`'s content.

Answer (score -1):

Even though these may not be form controls intended to hit the server, i would still put the value attribute for each of the inputs.

So for the 'check-0' input, i'd put in a `value` attribute of `100` (to represent the $100).

Then, a bit of javascript logic should make it easy to update the price value.

So something like this should do it (http://jsbin.com/orodow/1/edit):

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check-0" type="checkbox" value="100" />
        <label for="check-0">$100</label>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check-1" type="checkbox" value="50" />
        <label for="check-1">$50</label>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check-2" type="checkbox" value="20" />
        <label for="check-2">$20</label>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="price"></div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var inputs = $('.check input:checkbox');
        function updatePrice(){
            var value = 0;
            inputs.filter(':checked').each(function(){
                value += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            });
            $('.price').html('$' + value);
        }
        inputs.change(updatePrice);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should use the `click` event for checkboxes and radio buttons. And you are attempting to use `parseInt` on a string that has "$" in it...and will fail.

Comment: you shouldn't use the click event for checkboxes, as that would mean anyone interacting with that control using scripting would fail. The change event in jquery is built for this specific purpose.

I'm using parseInt on the value of the input, assuming its a numerical value. Obviously if the value of the input has included the $ string in it, it would fail.

Comment: You clearly don't know about the click/change events for checkboxes and radio buttons. And if you knew the thing would fail if the value had "$" in it, why would you post a solution without accommodating it or proposing a change?